# Why does the .touch() method not raise an error if the file already exists

Tags: python, filesystems

When you create a directory with mkdir() you have to set its exist_ok parameter to True (as shown below) to prevent a FileExistsError if that directory already exists.

```
from pathlib import Path
directory = Path.home() / "new_directory"
directory.mkdir(exist_ok = True)
```

But when you create a file with .touch(), you dont have to set any parameter. Even if the file that you are creating already exists, no error is raised. Why is this?

Comment: Because `touch` by default has `exist_ok=True` as opposed to `mkdir`

Comment: It behaves similar to the `touch` command available on Unix like operating systems.